# On input field mouse hover display tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing rating star when we hover on any star I want to display tooltip as far now I tried to like this there is a problem in jquery I couldn't target proper class name I don't have an idea how to write that class. I used input type radio and label how I will load this attributes in jquery can anyone suggest me to achieve that functionality.

thanks in Advance...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=rating]").on('mouseenter', showBox);
    $("input[name=rating]").on('mouseleave', hideBox);

    function showBox(e) {
        var x = e.pageX - 80;
        var y = e.pageY + 20;
        $('#tooltip_block').fadeIn();
        $('#tooltip_block').offset({ left: x, top: y });
    }

    function hideBox() {
        $('#tooltip_block').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

```css
    .rating_widgets {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.rating {
    border: none;
    float: left;
}

    .rating > input {
        display: none;
    }

    .rating > label:before {
        margin: 5px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        display: inline-block;
        content: "\f005";
    }

    .rating > .half:before {
        content: "\f089";
        position: absolute;
    }

    .rating > label {
        color: #ddd;
        float: right;
    }

    .rating > input:checked ~ label,
    .rating:not(:checked),
    .rating:not(:checked) {
        color: #FFD700;
    }

    .rating > input:checked,
    .rating > input:checked,
    .rating > input:checked ~ label,
    .rating > input:checked ~ label {
        color: #FFED85;
    }

#tooltip_block {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating_widgets">
    <fieldset class="rating">
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" />
        <label class="full" for="star5"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" />
        <label class="half" for="star4half"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
        <label class="full" for="star4"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" />
        <label class="half" for="star3half"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
        <label class="full" for="star3"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" />
        <label class="half" for="star2half"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
        <label class="full" for="star2"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" />
        <label class="half" for="star1half"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
        <label class="full" for="star1"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" />
        <label class="half" for="starhalf"></label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="tooltip_block">
    <div class="top_bar">4.2 stars out of 5 stars</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with the fact that the input fields aren't the ones you're actually hovering on, it's the labels.

This should work (Note that I've also replaced fadeIn() / fadeOut() with show() / hide() as mouse movements queue up the fade animations and make it flicker if you move your mouse around the star).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("label").hover(showBox, hideBox);

  function showBox(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - 80;
    var y = e.pageY + 20;

  $('#tooltip_block .rating_value').html($('#' + $(this).attr('for')).val());
    $('#tooltip_block').show();
    $('#tooltip_block').offset({ left: x, top: y });
  }
   
  function hideBox(){
     $('#tooltip_block').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.rating_widgets {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}
.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}
.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.rating > input:checked ~ label, 
.rating:not(:checked),
.rating:not(:checked){ color: #FFD700;  }

.rating > input:checked, 
.rating > input:checked,
.rating > input:checked ~ label, 
.rating > input:checked ~ label { 
 color: #FFED85;
} 
#tooltip_block {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a2e210f715.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating_widgets">
 <fieldset class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5"/>
  <label class = "full" for="star5"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="star4half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class = "full" for="star4"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="star3half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class = "full" for="star3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="star2half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class = "full" for="star2"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="star1half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class = "full" for="star1"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="starhalf"></label>
 </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="tooltip_block">
 <div class="top_bar"><span class="rating_value"></span> stars out of 5 stars</div>
</div>
```

**edit**

This is the code that's inserting the values into the hover boxes

```
$('#tooltip_block .rating_value').html($('#' + $(this).attr('for')).val());
```

if you want to get rid of them remove that line of javascript (you should probably remove

```
<span class="rating_value"></span>
```

from the hover div as well then as it serves no purpose without that bit of js).

**edit #2**

As far as the hover showing up inbetween the stars - I updated your css. The thing is you were setting

```
.rating > label:before {
    margin: 5px;
    ...
}
```

which effectively makes the elements that show your stars press up right besides one another. You can use

```
.rating > label { 
    ...
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.rating > .half:before { 
    ...
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Instead to create margins around the label elements

Comment: hover I'm getting value also I don't want `value` how to remove.

Comment: when I hover in the middle of the stars also getting the tooltip but  I want exactly hover on star tooltip appear.

Comment: @husna I added info on which lines are adding the values to your hover boxes

Comment: as far as their position is concerned it's still using your styles / position code - you want them to show up right below the star that's being hovered?

Comment: thanks can you tell hover in the middle of the star also getting the tooltip.

Comment: @Husna Added an edit explaining why youre getting the the hovers inbetween the stars, and edited the code so that it doesn't do that any more